# Selenium Webdriver not working on Rasberry Pi 4

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, raspberry-pi4

I would like to use Selenium on a Rasberry Pi4. Somehow it can't find the driver even though I installed it.

To install Selenium I already did these things.

python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate

So I could run pip install Selenium

```
Traceback (most recent call last):in get_path
   path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          driver = webdriver.Firefox('/usr/bin/firefox')
```

Can anyone explain whats wrong and how i can solve these Problem?

I also did this guide   https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/can-i-run-selenium-webdriver-using-firefox-as-the-browser